# ../../ offline vs cpanel to not have to change tags in cpanel

Tags: html

I do a lot of off line programming.

Sometimes for example this path /a/b/c/d.html
to go backwards to an anchor at a/a.html

I frequently see ../ or ../../  what do they mean, how are they used?
how do I use them and not have to put the entire path of the website in,
if the main site is html.com 
how do I use the folders without using html

example I want the anchor at a/a.html without using html.com/a/a.html
would this work the same to not have to use it?  ../a/a.html
did not work in offline mode

explain please

so that I don't have to re write the links from offline to public html
and the sites name

Answer (score 0):

`../image.jpg` means 'go up one directory and use image.jpg'

`./image.jpg` means use the image in this directory

`/image.jpg` means 'use the image from the root directory of the website'

So this example:

```
<img src"../../images/image.jpg" alt="an image">
```

Uses the image from 2 directory levels up and then go in the images directory and then use image.jpg.

That should get you started.

Comment: my condition is in cpanel, the full length example

Comment: but i need to get back to the home at b/b.html  but in offline it does not work, only inthe cpanel, it works using a.com/b/b.html see?  offline load does not take, so what do I use in offline, that onlinewill accept?  many manythanks for help, nice to meet you.